# Finding if value exists in any column recursively

Tags: java, recursion, jaxb

Our company uses an old version of JAXB so it does not allow generics. Other than that, I am using recursive calls because `Rows` can have subrows and I want to find out if any of the rows for the given column id `i` has any values.

I am interested to know if I got the recursion right.

```
private static boolean anyCellHasValue(CommonRowType row, int i) {

    CustomCellType cell = (CustomCellType)row.getCustomRow().getCell().get(i);

    if(!CELL_EMPTY.equals(cell.getType())) {
        return true ;
    }

    if (row.getChildren() != null && row.getChildren().getRowData() != null && 
        !row.getChildren().getRowData().isEmpty()) {
        for (int k = 0; k < row.getChildren().getRowData().size(); k++) {
            if(anyCellHasValue((CommonRowType) row.getChildren().getRowData().get(k), i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This site is more about the readability and structure of code rather than actual correctness. I will comment on that and maybe a more readable program will help you find any potential errors?

I would recommend that you:

- Extract complex if statements to their own methods describing the test
- Use the new style java iteration instead of the old for loop
- Reduce the block nesting level by returning early when you know you have a negative match
- Use good naming for all variables. In this case the variable i desperately needs a better name!

This should produce (sans renaming of i) code that look something like this: (not compiled or tested in any way :))

```
private static boolean anyCellHasValue(CommonRowType row, int i) {
    if (isNonEmptyCellType(row, i)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!hasChildren(row)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (CommonRowType childRow : row.getChildren().getRowData()) {
        if (anyCellHasValue(childRow, i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static boolean isNonEmptyCellType(CommonRowType row, int i) {
    CustomCellType cell = (CustomCellType)row.getCustomRow().getCell().get(i);
    return !CELL_EMPTY.equals(cell.getType()));
}

private static boolean hasChildren(CommonRowType row) {
    return row.getChildren() != null 
            && row.getChildren().getRowData() != null 
            && !row.getChildren().getRowData().isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd improve *@kyck-ling*'s `hasChildren` method a little bit:

```
private static boolean hasChildren(CommonRowType row) {
    final Children children = row.getChildren();
    if (children == null) {
        return false;
    }

    final RowData rowData = children.getRowData();
    if (rowData == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (rowData.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now it uses [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) and a few local variables to remove some duplication like `row.getChildren().getRowData()`.
Anyway, it still violates [the Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). A better solution is to create a `hasChildren` method in the `Children` class. See also: [Feature envy smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell).

Another interesting point that that it seems that the `children.getRowData()` returns a collection which could be `null`. It reminds me the *Item 43: Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls* chapter of *Effective Java, 2nd Edition*.

Comment: maybe replace the last two if-clauses with return rowData != null && !rowData.isEmpty();

Comment: @kyck-ling I'm not sure about replacing those.  I tend to find double negatives quite hard to follow without doing a double take.  Perhaps !(rowData == null || rowData.isEmpty()) or put it into it's own method?

Comment: @dreza its not a double negative but sure, there are other ways to write it. My main point was that seven rows of code could be one row.

Comment: @kyck-ling: Source code storage costs almost nothing but developer time is expensive, so I'd choose the cheaper one, which is easier to understand, therefore easier (cheaper) to maintain and less error-prone.

Comment: @palacsint I'm not talking about storage but readability (and thus developer time) same as you. But I guess this boils down to personal choice more than anything else.